# IdentityModel RefreshToken impementation issue

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, identityserver4, openid-connect, identity

I use the following code to log in via OIDC. This is a UWP app with `IdentityModel.OidcClient 5.0.0`

```
LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest
{
   FrontChannelExtraParameters = new IdentityModel.Client.Parameters(parameter)
};

LoginResult result = await IdentityManager.GetOidcClient().LoginAsync(loginRequest);
```

So in the `LoginResult`, I have the `RefreshToken IdentityToken AccessToken` to use in the code. What I don't understand is after token expiration I get `HTTP401` and I call

```
RefreshTokenResult result = await IdentityManager.GetOidcClient().RefreshTokenAsync(
                    result.RefreshToken);
```

This is also getting success. My issue is how do I get the `RefreshTokenResult`'s values such as `RefreshToken IdentityToken AccessToken` back to the `LoginResult`? (`LoginResult` has internal-set properties is the reason I can't set it)

Or Am I doing this wrong? I can't happen to find a single sample with an OIDC implementation. Appreciate your support.

[image]

Comment: The LoginResult class seems like it doesn't allow you to re-use it with different values by design. Why would you need to put the values back into the LoginResult?

Comment: @Randy hi, how do you propose I update the refreshed tokens?

Comment: Assuming you want to always keep updated values in one object, instead of using the LoginResult outright, you could use a new custom-defined class that holds the string access, identity, and refresh tokens. Then when you receive a RefreshTokenResult, you can update the token strings in your custom-defined class with the ones defined in the RefreshTokenResult

Comment: @Randy I thought the same. I’ll try that way. Thank you for the support.